# implements OAuth 2.0 with Auth0 and Apache CXF

Tags: oauth-2.0, cxf, auth0

I am currently working on an OAuth 2.0 token server using Auth0 and apache CXF. My requirements are like the following: I have 2 kinds of consumers:
The client, wrote on Angular2, that use the Auth0 service flow, and
the server, wrote on Java, that use the access token, created by the client.

Now, I send the access token from the client to the server inside the headers and it works fine. The problem is that the CXF returns **javax.ws.rs.NotAuthorizedException: HTTP 401 Unauthorized**, when trying to validate it.

I followed the Apache CXF documentation and add to my beans.xml file the following code, but it seems that still something is missing.

http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-oauth2.html#JAX-RSOAuth2-AccessTokenValidationService

```
<bean id="tvServiceClientFactory" class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.client.JAXRSClientFactoryBean">
    <property name="address" value="https://MY_DOMAIN.auth0.com/userinfo"/>
    <property name="headers">
        <map>
            <entry key="Accept" value="application/json"/>
            <entry key="Content-Type" value="application/x-www-form-urlencoded"/>
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="tvServiceClient" factory-bean="tvServiceClientFactory" factory-method="createWebClient"/>

<bean id="tokenValidator" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.AccessTokenValidatorClient">
    <property name="tokenValidatorClient" ref="tvServiceClient"/>
</bean>

<bean id="oauthFilter" class="org.apache.cxf.rs.security.oauth2.filters.OAuthRequestFilter">
    <property name="tokenValidator" ref="tokenValidator"/>
</bean>
<!-- / CXF Auth2.0 Filters -->

<jaxrs:server id="services" address="/PartMfg">
    <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
        <bean class="MY_SERVICE"/>
    </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    <jaxrs:providers>
        <bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider"/>
        <ref bean="oauthFilter"/>
    </jaxrs:providers>
</jaxrs:server>
```

I tried to validate the access token on Postman and I got a response code of 200, so there is no problem with the token itself.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out. The CXF Validator class expect the response to return a specific class. The Auth0 serivce returns a Json with the user info.

What I did is to create my own filter class thats inherits form OAuthRequestFilter.

```
    public void filter(ContainerRequestContext context) {
    // Try to get authenticate and get user info
    WebClient webClient = WebClient.create(https://YOUR_AUTH_DOMAIN/userinfo);
    webClient.type("application/json").accept("application/json");
    String token = context.getHeaderString("Authorization");
    webClient.header("Authorization", token);
    Response response = webClient.get();
    // Check if authorized
    if (!(response.getStatus() == Response.Status.OK.getStatusCode() || response.getStatus() == Response.Status.NO_CONTENT.getStatusCode()
            || response.getStatus() == Response.Status.TEMPORARY_REDIRECT.getStatusCode())) {
        AuthorizationUtils.throwAuthorizationFailure(this.supportedSchemes, this.realm);
    }
[[REST OF YOUR HANDLE]]
```